# Transparent Gradient with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to make a rectangle mask with rounded corners which also would have a gradient (or inner shadow)

```
class RoundRectLayer : CALayer {

    var rect : CGRect = .zero

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        ctx.saveGState()
        var path = CGPath(roundedRect: rect,
                          cornerWidth: rect.size.width / 10,
                          cornerHeight: rect.size.height / 10,
                          transform: nil)
        ctx.addPath(path)
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
        path = path.copy(strokingWithWidth: 4.0,
                         lineCap: CGLineCap.butt,
                         lineJoin: CGLineJoin.bevel,
                         miterLimit: 0)

        ctx.addPath(path)
        let colors = [
            UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
            UIColor.red.cgColor
        ]
        ctx.fillPath()
        ctx.restoreGState()
    }
}
```

This is where I got so far, just a rounded rect. Radial and Linear gradients seem to be not the ones I expected.

Picture for reference (just a clear color instead of a white in the middle)
[image]

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I'm still having trouble with it. *ACInnerShadowLayer* from [Inner shadow effect on UIView layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer/19535353) got the effect I want, just there's a small issue. I would also like to have the same color background as that shadows. And now I only have that square in the middle and clear background

Comment: Unclear what result you want. What’s wrong with the result you are getting?

Comment: @matt not sure how to explain. Well line gradient is just from one point to other, radial also goes from one point. And this gradient right here is more like inner shadow that goes around the border

Comment: Well, if you can’t say what you want, no one can say how to get it. You said “I'm trying to make a rectangle mask with rounded corners which also would have a gradient (or inner shadow)” and it looks to me like that’s exactly what you’ve got in your picture. What’s the problem?

Comment: @matt picture is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Ah. Well, I had an answer that describes  how to do that, but someone downvoted it just today, so I deleted it.

Comment: However, I would point out that your code has no gradient and no mask so it’s not surprising if you don’t get a gradient mask.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011737/create-a-radial-gradient-mask-to-create-a-hole-in-the-picture

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093305/swift-3-how-to-create-blurred-side-edges-corners-of-a-uiimageview

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249409/how-to-cut-out-a-hole-with-radial-gradient-in-view